# Access file characteristics / attributes in bash loop

Tags: bash, loops, filesize

I'm learning more about bash scripting. When looping through files in a directory, I want to be able to echo out more than just the filename. How do I access associated file data?

This example code I have used to list all files in a folder.

```
for file in .* *; do echo "$file"; done
```

What do I add need to do to access the $file size or date? I noticed it's not as easy as just $file.size and $file.date.

Comment: Take a look at stat(1).

Comment: It depends on what *associated* file data you want to see but indeed `stat` may be a good start.

Comment: This question conflates different things: accessing file attributes, printing some file attributes in a bash script, and looping over a sequence in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you call them "file", what you get are just strings with the file names.
In each iteration of the for loop, you can use $file with other commands ( for example "stat" or "ls -l"), to extract information about the files, and then you will have to parse its output (with "awk" or "sed").

So the solution will be:

```
for file in .* *; do COMMAND_TO_GET_INFO "$file" | COMMAND_TO_PARSE_OUTPUT ; done
```

where COMMAND_TO_GET_INFO and COMMAND_TO_PARSE_OUTPUT could be different commands according to what you need.